# PostGIS ST_Distance_Spheroid or Haversine

Tags: postgis, haversine

I used `ST_Distance_Spheroid` in PostgreSQL (with Postgis) to calculate the distance between Woking and Edinburgh like as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pointsTable (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location Point NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO pointsTable (name, location) VALUES 
( 'Woking', '(51.3168, -0.56)' ),
( 'Edinburgh', '(55.9533, -3.1883)' );

SELECT ST_Distance_Spheroid(geometry(a.location), geometry(b.location), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
FROM pointsTable a, pointsTable b
WHERE a.id=1 AND b.id=2;
```

I got a result of 592km (592,053.100454442 meters).

Unfortunately, when I used various sources on the web to make the same calculation I consistently got around the 543km mark which is different by 8.2%.

- [source 1](http://tjpeiffer.com/crowflies.html) - 338 miles (543.958 km)
- [source 2](https://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm) - 544.410km
- [source 3](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) - 543.8km

Luckily, the third source clarified that they were using the haversine formula. I am not sure about the other two sources.

Did I do something wrong in my queries or is this down to a difference in the formulas used? If so, which calculation is closest to the shortest distance a crow could fly, keeping a constant elevation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [swapped](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) the latitude and the longitude. If you put them in the right order you would get  544 430m. The distance computation is using the great circle arcs, which is the true shortest distance between points over a sphere.

```sql
WITH src AS (
  select st_geomfromtext('POINT(-0.56 51.3168)',4326) pt1,
         st_geomfromtext('POINT(-3.1883 55.9533)',4326) pt2)
SELECT 
   ST_DistanceSpheroid(pt1, pt2, 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') Dist_sphere,
   ST_Distance(pt1::geography, pt2::geography) Dist_great_circle
FROM src;

   dist_sphere    | dist_great_circle
------------------+-------------------
 544430.941199621 |   544430.94119962
(1 row)
```

On a side note, there is a warning

> ST_Distance_Spheroid signature was deprecated in 2.2.0. Please use
>   ST_DistanceSpheroid

Comment: Thats the best solution I could have hoped for. I got caught out by thinking everything is latitude, longitude, but of course points are in x,y format.